# Byteman 4.0.14 verification commands after installation

Tags: java, jboss, byteman

I wrote script in powershell n linux script to install byteman, installation is successful after checking system variables as byteman home,will be added to varaibles and path.
But how do I check it whether it has installed it or not.

Answer (score 0):

It you started the agent with a socket listener enabled then you can test whether the agent is running and list whatever rules have been installed/injected using the bmsubmit script provided in the bin directory of the Byteman download.

Byteman provides scripts as part of the Byteman downloads that you can use to ensure Byteman is installed. Take a look in the bin directory of a download and you will find scripts for both Linux and Windows. On Linux you can use

bmjava.sh to start a Java app with Byteman installed at startup

bminstall.sh to install Byteman into an already running Java application

The Byteman tutorial (part 1) explains how to use bmjava, bmsubmit and bminstall on Linus and Windows. I suggest you read it and follow the instructions to run the example code with Byteman. You will find a link to the tutorial on the [Byteman docs page](https://byteman.jboss.org/docs.html)